# How to mock external module

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I´m having trouble figuring out how to test, with jest, if an external library method is being called when a function in my module gets called.

Given this typescript class:

```
import transport from "app/customApiLibrary";
const { api } = transport;

// myServiceClass.ts
export class MyServiceClass {
  getSomeStuff(): Promise<any> {
    return api.get("myservice/end/point/");
  }

}
let serviceStuff = new MyServiceClass();
export default serviceStuff;
```

How do I test that when getSomeStuff is executed, api.get gets called?

I tried spyOn but it didn´t work.
And I don´t think it´s the right approach. 
I think that simply mocking transport´s api methods is the way, but I don´t know how to build that mock.

```
// const spy = jest.spyOn(transport, "get"); 
// doesn´t work.  Cannot spy the get property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

// myServiceClass.spec.ts
import serviceStuff from "./myServiceClass";
import transport from "app/util/transport";

describe("MyServiceClass", () => {
  it("when getSomeStuff", () => {
    expect(serviceStuff.getSomeStuff).toBeDefined(); // checks
    serviceStuff.getSomeStuff();
    // expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); see above
  });
});
```

I´ve tried some embarrassing variations of this kind of mock:

```
jest.mock('app/util/transport', () => ({
  api: class {
     get() {
      return {
        promise: true,
      };
    }
  },
}));
```

But I keep getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are doing almost right.

At first, you cannot mock `default` export by specifying `transport` in module path like `jest.mock('app/util/transport')` if module itself is in `'app/customApiLibrary'`. But maybe it's just a accident error while adopting real code into Stackoverflow question...

Your `transport` in sample code is a default export from 'app/customApiLibrary'. To mock default export you may either make that explicitly:

```
jest.mock('app/customApiLibrary', () => ({
  default: {
    api: class {
     get: jest.fn(() => ({
         promise: true,
       })),
     }
  }
}));
```

Or may use function-that-returns-function in `jest.mock`(I personally never done it that way but [articles say](https://medium.com/codeclan/mocking-es-and-commonjs-modules-with-jest-mock-37bbb552da43) it's possible)

```
jest.mock('app/customApiLibrary', () => () => ({
  api: class {
   get: jest.fn(() => ({
       promise: true,
     })),
   }
}));
```

See, I'm declaring `get` as `jest.fn()`.

That means in `it()` I'd be able to check if it has been called:

```
import transport from `app/customApiLibrary`;

jest.mock(...)

it('do', () => {
    // doing something
    // check any call for parameters
    expect(transport.api.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('param1', 'param2');
    // or check if it has been called particular amount of times
    expect(transport.api.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    // or event verify specific calls or particular params by accessing `.mock.calls` prop
    expect(transport.api.get.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual('_temp_')

})
```

To ensure call count is cleaned each time we need to clear that data:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  transport.api.get.mockClear();
})
```

Without `spyOn` or setting function as `jest.fn` it would not be possible.